# Select most recent N records for each user - INFORMIX DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, informix

I have a table with the following fields:

```
USER_ID
SITE_ID
STATION_ID
Login_DateTime
```

I would like to pull out the most recent N (let's say 5) records for each User/Site combination.

Can you please help me to create the query for MS Access and Informix DBs?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this using SQL that is compatible with both Informix and MS Access is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where (select count(*)
       from table as t2
       where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.site_id = t.site_id and
             t2.login_datetime >= t.login_datetime
      ) <= 5;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The answer is correct; however, the query takes a considerable amount of time when dealing with 30000 records. I will wait for a possible improved solution before accepting. Thanks again

Comment: You can add indexes on `table(user_id, site_id, login_datetime)` to speed the query in both databases.